# prove that if $f-g$=$o(g)$ as x approaches a then $f-g$=$o(f)$ as $x$ approaches $a$

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove that if $f-g = O(g)$ as x approaches a then $f-g=O(f)$ as x approaches a (f, g - functions, o - Landau symbol)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $f-g=\omicron_a (g)$. This is equivalent to $\lim_a \frac{f-g}{g}=0$. Then $\lim_a \frac{f}{g}=1$. By taking the inverse, $\lim_a \frac{g}{f}=1$. We conclude that $\lim_a \frac{f-g}{f}=0$, which exactly says that $f-g=\omicron_a (f)$.